# Auto-encoding Catalyst::View::JSON

Tags: json, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I use DBIx class for selecting data from database;
I send response from controller to client using serialization to json using `Catalyst::View::JSON`

But utf8-data selected from database needs to be decoded to perl-string from utf-8 before sending to client like this

```perl
use Encode;

...

sub get_fruits :Path('getfruits') :Args(0) {
    my $fruits = [$c->model('DB::Fruit')->search({})->hashref_array];
    # Hated encode data loop
    foreach (@$fruits) {
        $_->{name} = decode('utf8', $_->{name});
    }
    $c->stash({fruits => $fruits});
    $c->forward('View::JSON');
}
```

Is it possible to decode data automatically in the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be as simple as ensuring that Catalyst::View::JSON is using a JSON encoder that supports UTF8 encoding. I believe that if you use JSON::XS with Catalyst::View::JSON it will perform UTF8 encoding by default. You can make sure that Catalyst::View::JSON is using JSON::XS using the json_driver config variable.

Alternatively you can override JSON encoding in Catalyst::View::JSON as [detailed in the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Catalyst-View-JSON-0.33/lib/Catalyst/View/JSON.pm#OVERRIDING_JSON_ENCODER)

Comment: I alredy tried to override encoding (serializer) but it didn't work. So i answered this question. I would like a working example to do that =)

Answer (score 2):

The Catalyst model **always** has to ensure that the data is **decoded**, regardless of where it is used. The view has to ensure the data is **encoded** correctly.
You have to make sure that your model decodes data coming from the database. If you are using DBIx::Class read [Using Unicode](https://metacpan.org/module/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.08210/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Using-Unicode).

Comment: DBIx model provides data in right encoding, wich normally presented in HTML page generated from Template Toolkit. But data serialized to JSON send to client in invalid encoding. Example: "ÐÐ°ÑÑÐ½ÐµÑ" instead of "Партнер" (cyrrilic).

Comment: Its DBIC, DBIx is a whole namespace where DBIx::Class is only a single distro. If decoding solves the problem you double-encode your data currently. As JSON is always UTF-8 and View::JSON encodes your data as UTF-8 it isn't decoded after reading it from your database.

Comment: I agree, using Unicode catalyst plugin is enough. Tested with postgresql with lots of cyrillic data + catalyst 5.90042-2 + DBIX-Class 0.08192-1 from debian stable. There are some other issues with JSON serialization, like encoding booleans as 0/1 instead of false/true, but encoding is ok.